# Cannot insert multiple rows into table

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-mysql

**The Situation**

I have a flask app and I need to insert multiple values into it at once:

The Mysql table has 3 columns: name, email, password

The Form has three inputs: name[], email[], password[]

**The Error**

> TypeError: not enough arguments for format string

**The Code**

```py
        @app.route("/insert", methods=["POST", "GET"])
        def insert(): 
            cur = mysql.connection.cursor() 
            if request.method == 'POST': 
                names = request.form.getlist('name[]') 
                emails = request.form.getlist('email[]')
                passwords = request.form.getlist('passwprd[]') 
                data = [names, emails, passwords] 
                for value in data: 
                    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)',[value]) 
                mysql.connection.commit() 
                cur.close() 
                flash('New record created successfully') 
            return redirect('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code you it looks like the data variable has been created wrong.

If looking at this example:

```py
names = ['peter', 'patty', 'micheal']
emails = ['example@gmail.com','test@gmail.com','foo@gmail.com']
passwords = ['asghgshsdgds','123','aasasa']
data =[names, emails, passwords]
print(data)
#[['peter', 'patty', 'micheal'],['example@gmail.com', 'test@gmail.com', 'foo@gmail.com'], ['asghgshsdgds', '123', 'aasasa']]
```

Where as doing something like:

```py
data = list()
if len(names) == len(emails) == len(passwords):
    for i, val in enumerate(names):
        data.append([names[i], emails[i], passwords[i]])
print(data)
# [['peter', 'example@gmail.com', 'asghgshsdgds'], ['patty', 'test@gmail.com', '123'], ['micheal', 'foo@gmail.com', 'aasasa']]
```

This is the main issue I believe.

So the solution would be:

```py
    @app.route("/insert", methods=["POST", "GET"])
    def insert(): 
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor() 
        if request.method == 'POST': 
            names = request.form.getlist('name[]') 
            emails = request.form.getlist('email[]')
            passwords = request.form.getlist('passwprd[]') 
            data = list()
            if len(names) == len(emails) == len(passwords):
                for i, val in enumerate(names):
                    data.append([names[i], emails[i], passwords[i]]) 
            for value in data: 
                cur.executemany('INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)', [value]) 
            mysql.connection.commit() 
            cur.close() 
            flash('New record created successfully') 
        return redirect('/')
```

***Edit***

After further [investigation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) I believe it can be made even further simplified with:

```py
    @app.route("/insert", methods=["POST", "GET"])
    def insert(): 
        cur = mysql.connection.cursor() 
        if request.method == 'POST': 
            names = request.form.getlist('name[]') 
            emails = request.form.getlist('email[]')
            passwords = request.form.getlist('passwprd[]') 
            data = list()
            if len(names) == len(emails) == len(passwords):
                for i, val in enumerate(names):
                    data.append([names[i], emails[i], passwords[i]])
            stmt = 'INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
            cursor.executemany(stmt, data)
            mysql.connection.commit() 
            cur.close() 
            flash('New record created successfully') 
        return redirect('/')
```

Comment: Sorry not insert form data to mysql.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand your comment?

Comment: don't worry dear. I make some changes in your code.   Now it is working.           
for value in data:
                cur.executemany('INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)',[value])

Comment: Excellent so the answer worked for you?

Comment: Yes. Thank you dear.

Comment: If you have a moment take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Get this while vote... Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Comment: Not the vote but you can accept the answer as the correct answer